# Android Lollipop: Can't run recompiled framework-res.apk: "Analysis Error"

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, apktool

I'm actually tweaking `/system/framework/framework-res.apk` to change some of Lollipop's new features. There's a bunch of XML files in that package for that purpose.

The issue is: I decompile and recompile the mentioned apk with apktool on my pc, without editing anything, just to try. Then I move the apk to my Samsung S5's `/sdcard` directory, tap it, and get the following error:

> "Analysis error. Couldn't perform this package's analysis (translation from spanish)".

When compiling, I get several warnings, mostly "translation not found" types. The same process with a phonegap self made app works perfectly.

I'm using:

- apktool_2.0.0rc3.jar
- jdk 1.7
- Windows 7 ultimate
- Android 5.0 on Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900F)
- I have deleted C:\Users\myuser\apktool\framework\1.apk file.

Could the problem be a signature issue?

Thanks.